# AppleScript to replace text in multiple files

Tags: perl, search, text, replace, applescript

I'm trying to come up with a general multi-purpose way of replacing text in multiple files through AppleScript.  This solution is using Perl.  Is there maybe a more elegant way of doing this?

```
set myFolder to choose folder with prompt "Choose a folder:"
tell application "Finder"
    try 
        set txtFiles to (every file in entire contents of myFolder whose name ends with ".txt") as alias list
    on error 
        try
            set txtFiles to ((every file in entire contents of myFolder whose name ends with ".txt") as alias) as list
        on error 
            set txtFiles to {}
        end try
    end try
    set myFiles to txtFiles
end tell

repeat with CurrentFile in myFiles
    set CurrentFile to CurrentFile as string

    do shell script "perl -pi -e  's/replace/me/g; s/andme/too/g;' " & quoted form of (POSIX path of CurrentFile)

end repeat
```

Also, ideally, I'd like to make the Perl part a bit more readable, having each search/replace pattern on a separate line, but the `do shell script` in AppleScript seems to be unable to deal with line breaks, e.g.,

```
do shell script "perl -pi -e  '
s/replace/me/g; 
s/andme/too/g;
s/andhere/measwell/g;
' " & quoted form of (POSIX path of CurrentFile)
```

So essentially, is there a better/more elegant way of doing this? 
Doesn't necessarily have to be with `perl`, yet for a non-expert I continue to find `perl` the easiest way for handling this, especially as it's great at regexes (the solution should be able to do regexes).

Comment: Unrelated but the second line `set txtFiles to ((every file in...` throws always an error.

Comment: @vadian The second line is supposed to handle the case when there's only one single matching file in the respective folder.

Comment: But you get no error in the first line if there is only one txt file, not even if there is no txt file at all, actually you can remove the entire try block. And the syntax `whose name extension is "txt"` is preferable

Comment: @vadian  You're actually right.  Thanks for pointing that out, that makes it much nicer.  I extracted that code from some other workflow (I don't remember what the original purpose was, maybe there was something to it, or maybe AppleScript years ago worked differently), but in this case it's clearly redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](http://applescript.wikia.com/wiki/Line-Continuation_Symbol), you could use

```
do shell script "perl -pi -e  '" & ¬
" s/replace/me/g;" & ¬
" s/andme/too/g;" & ¬
" s/andhere/measwell/g;" & ¬
"' " & quoted form of (POSIX path of CurrentFile)
```

Pardon my lack of knowledge of AppleScript, but maybe you can even do something like the following:

```
set PerlProg to "" & ¬
"s/replace/me/g; " & ¬
"s/andme/too/g; " & ¬
"s/andhere/measwell/g;"

set PerlCmd to "perl -i -pe'" & PerlProg & "'"

do shell script PerlCmd & " " & quoted form of (POSIX path of CurrentFile)
```

Comment: That works thanks very much.  I like the second block. (Actually the `set xyz` in AppleScript requires a `to` instead of the `=`)

Comment: Oops, yeah, I saw that `to` was needed; I'm just so used to using `=`.